# Android Swapping images on clicking

Tags: java, android, xml

I have two ImageViews and I want to swap the images with each other. I know that I can use setImageDrawable or setImageBitmap methods to change the images, but it's not exactly what I want. What I want is the images should change their places with each other.

I noticed that onFade1() is not getting called but onFade2().
On clicking the image nothing happens. Please help! I guess there's some problem with the alpha value in XML file

Java Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView image1;
ImageView image2;

public void onFade1(View view){
    image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_img1);
    image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_img2);

    image1.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
    image2.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
    System.out.println("Hi");
}

public void onFade2(View view){
    image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_img1);
    image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_img2);

    image2.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
    image1.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
    System.out.println("Hello");
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

XML code:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/image1"
    android:id="@+id/iv_img1"
    android:onClick="onFade1" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/image2"
    android:id="@+id/iv_img2"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:onClick="onFade2" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onFade2` is only called because it refers to the last `ImageView` in xml which is the top most and the one will always get the Touch, even if the alpha is Zero. What you have to do is to add An animation listener and to make image clicked Visibility to be GONE

```
 public void onFade1(View view) {
    image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_img1);
    image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_img2);

    image1.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            image1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            System.out.println("image1 Gone");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
    image2.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            image2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            System.out.println("image2 VISIBLE");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
    System.out.println("Hi");
}

public void onFade2(View view) {
    image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_img1);
    image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_img2);

    image2.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            image2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            System.out.println("image2 GONE");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });

    image1.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            System.out.println("image1 VISIBLE");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, Please mark it as accepted answer to make this question as "Answered"

Answer (score 0):

Change the `XML` to this:

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/image1"
android:id="@+id/iv_img1"
android:onClick="onFade" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/image2"
    android:id="@+id/iv_img2"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:onClick="onFade" />
```

and the `Activity` code to this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView image1;
ImageView image2;

public void onFade(View view){
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.iv_img1:
            MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.iv_img2)
                .setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
            ((ImageView) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.iv_img2))
                .animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
        case R.id.iv_img2:
            MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.iv_img1)
                .setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
            ((ImageView) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.iv_img1))
                .animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: @BuckyBunny, **`Happy Coding`** `:)`